# Socket.io delay in emit/receive when more than 80 concurrent connections are happening

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a very simple example.

**Server**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('socket.io');
var wsServer = WebSocketServer.listen(8080);

wsServer.on('connection', function (ws) {
    ws.on('data', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

**Client**

```
var WebSocketServer = require('socket.io-client');
var wsClient = WebSocketServer.connect(server, {'force new connection': true});

wsClient.on('connect', function () {
    wsClient.emit('data', {message: true});
})
```

I then instantiate concurrent calls:

```
var ClientSocket = require('./path-to-client');
var numInstances = 100;
for (var i = 0; i < numInstances; i++) {
    (function (client_id) {
        var WavegetInstant = new ClientSocket();
    })("client" + i);
}
```

This works fine when `numInstances` is less than 80. But when it goes over 80, then there is about `2min` of delay before messages are transmitted/received. If I `console.log` right in `wsServer.on('connection')`, then I do get a connection and a unique web socket id, its just the `on('data') OR emit('data')` being delayed.

Help is appreciated

Comment: So, you're creating >80 websocket connections from one client?

Comment: I presume you're trying to simulate >80 clients simultaneously connected.  It might do an OK simulation on the server, but on the client end, you're running all >80 connections over one internet connection, one network card and one single threaded JS engine so that's not a very realistic response experience.  Normally, this traffic would be processed by >80 CPUs, internet connections and JS engines, not just one.

Comment: Okay, so how do I load test my server then?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=cloud+load+test&gws_rd=ssl